# Angular object array value throw error of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I am working on Angular 6 application. I have behaviour variable of Input, once I received data, I map to surveyInfo object. I have surveyInfoDataModel class as shown below; followed by I am trying to display this data by reading surveyInfo object in template but go error

### error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'surveyId' of undefined
```

### component

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() surveySelectedToGetInfo: BehaviorSubject<any>;

ngOnInit() {

this.surveySelectedToGetInfo.subscribe(surveyDataItem=>{
  debugger;
  if(surveyDataItem!=null){
    this.loadSurveyInformation(surveyDataItem);
  }
 });
}

 private loadSurveyInformation(selectedSurveyObject:any):any{
 var mappedObject = this.mapSurveyInfo(selectedSurveyObject);
}

 private mapSurveyInfo(survey:any):SurveyInfoDataModel{
 if(survey!=null){

  this.surveyInfo = new SurveyInfoDataModel(
    survey.consultationId,
    survey.surveyId,
    survey.surveyIdNum,
    survey.surveyName
  );  
 }
  return this.surveyInfo;
}
```

### Survey Info DataModel class

```
export class SurveyInfoDataModel{
    surveyId:string;
    surveyIdNum:string;
    surveyName:string;
    consultationId:string;

constructor(consultationId, surveyId, surveyIdNum, surveyName ){
    this.consultationId =consultationId;
    this.surveyId = surveyId;
    this.surveyIdNum = surveyIdNum;
    this.surveyName = surveyName;

 }
}
```

### html template

```
<div class="surveyListInfoBlock">
 <div *ngIf="surveyInfo">
   {{surveyInfo.surveyId}}
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What happens if you changes `if(survey!=null){` to `if (typeof survery !== 'undefined' && survey!==null)` ?

Comment: I still got same error... i got mapped correctly and I can see data in this.surveyInfo debugger, thats why i am confused of where things go wrong

Comment: Are you sure that your observable `surveySelectedToGetInfo`  returns a value?

Comment: yes, confirm ... i can see data in debugger

Comment: i think i have issue in template ... i update my question with template block ...if you can kindly refer it .. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change `if(survey!=null)` to `if(!survey) return;`. Looks like you going to return `undefined` if there is no `survey` cause return statement is outside the brackets. If it will work, you'll need to check all props of this object on `undefined`. Also you need to add typing to this object.

```
private mapSurveyInfo(survey:any):SurveyInfoDataModel{
    if (!survey) return;

    this.surveyInfo = new SurveyInfoDataModel(
      survey.consultationId,
      survey.surveyId,
      survey.surveyIdNum,
      survey.surveyName
    );  

    return this.surveyInfo;
}
```

Comment: i think i have issue in template ... i update my question with template block ...if you can kindly refer it .. thanks

Comment: No, it's ok with template, try my snippet

Answer (score 1):

`Survey` in your case is undefined. Instead of testing if `survey` is null you can test for both null & undefined with this:

```
 if(!!survey){
  this.surveyInfo = new SurveyInfoDataModel(
    survey.consultationId,
    survey.surveyId,
    survey.surveyIdNum,
    survey.surveyName
  );  
 }
```